# Problem Saving Enupal Plugin Settings

Tags: plugin-enupalpdf

**Description**

I’m having an issue getting Enupal Snapshot working on our staging server. The settings do not want to save in the craft admin.

[image]

It isn’t obvious what the error is. I have checked my log files and this is the only error I see replating to Enupal's plugin. I think this is a red herring as I have this working on my local environment.

```
2019-11-13 09:16:37 [-][1][-][error][enupal\snapshot\Snapshot::error] Something went wrong when creating the PDF file: Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://franklin.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/?prefix=tools%2Finnovation-assessment%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://franklin.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/?prefix=tools%2Finnovation-assessment%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. run `which wkhtmltopdf` outputs `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`
2. Save path to plugin settings

**Additional info**
Craft version: 3.3.9
PHP version: 7.2.24
Database driver & version: MySQL 5.7.27
Plugin version: 1.2.6

Comment: Hi there, were you able to solve this issue? Did you check the permissions in your S3 bucket?

Comment: I belive this is an evironment issue. Still trying to solve. Works on local and production but not staging.

Answer (score 1):

> Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://franklin.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/?prefix=tools%2Finnovation-assessment%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://franklin.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/?prefix=tools%2Finnovation-assessment%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:

That's an AWS error, so I'm guessing you're trying to save the output to an S3 bucket, but the credentials you've configured the S3 buck with does not have "ListObjects" permissions on the bucket.